# Can I loop on a method?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am using a method to retrieve an enumerable and was wandering a silly thing : is it ok to loop on the method call? say I have a method `getDocuments` in a `Document` class that returns an `IEnumerable`, then can I do:

```
Document doc=new Document();
foreach(var item in doc.getDocuments())
{//Code here
}
```

Or is it better to assign a variable to that result and loop on the variable?

Comment: Have you tried it? If yes then what makes you think that it wouldn't be ok to do it? By the way, you are not looping on the "method call" you are looping on the return value of the method

Comment: Presumably you will want to name the loop variable something other than `doc`, but looks ok

Comment: for debugging purposes you should use a variable (it's easier to check a variable than a returnvalue of a method), but it would work either way

Comment: Yeah, that's OK. The only downside is in debugging..

Comment: @AlainD hah well spotted :p Thanks to all!

Comment: Valid C#... yes, debuggable code? not really.

Comment: @stuartd Oh so it's more of a bad practice then?

Comment: it is not a bad practice.  It is fine.

Comment: `getDocuments()` returning one `Document` or an array of `Document` ??

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal returning an  `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok to loop for a method result, it will be evaluated only once. So, it's not necessary to use a temporary variable.

Answer (score 4):

The method call is evaluated once and the returned `IEnumerable` is then used by the loop.

In short, what you are doing is fine.

There is the potential for a small gotcha though. If an expression tree is returned as an `IEnumerable`, and while the `foreach` is executing, the underlying datastructure is edited, it will throw an exception

Comment: Not sure I understood you on this one. Do you mean if another method in my `foreach` would modify the method that's called to loop, then I can have an exception?

Comment: Lets say you return a linq expression from that method. The underlying structure was a list. If something else then alters that list either within the execution block of the foreach, or on another thread, an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping on the same thing in both cases, the only difference is whether you also give it a name (by declaring a variable). You might want to do that for readability, or to access it multiple times - to enumerate over it multiple times<sup>1</sup>, or for easier debugging<sup>2</sup>.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Usually not recommended because of possible side-effects, or could simply be a waste of performance. It's often better to call `ToArray` or `ToList` before enumerating over the same collection multiple times.*

*<sup>2</sup> Note that if you "expand" the variable under the debugger, you are effectively enumerating over it, which may be problematic in the presence of side-effects (as mentioned above).*

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but be aware that if the method call returns a null reference rather than an empty `IEnumerable` you will get a `System.NullReferenceException` when you try to iterate it.

Storing the method call result in a variable instead would not in itself solve this problem, but would give you a chance to check for null before performing the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I think it's best to use a variable in my case since I want to test for these kinds of mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The doc.getDocuments() in your for loop evaluates and returns a result and it is on this result that the var doc is iterated upon. This method is not going to be called each time the loop runs. Hence it will be okay to use this method in the loop.